# How to run XCTest (UI test cases) of iOS mobile application in the azure pipeline?

Tags: ios, swift, azure-devops, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

How to run XCTest (UI test cases) of iOS mobile application in the Azure pipeline?

Tasks added in pipeline:

1. Install certificate
2. Install profile
3. Use Node 13.3.0
4. pod install
5. Xcode-> build action as "build-for-testing"
6. Test with Visual Studio App Center

At this final step "Test with Visual Studio App Center" we get error

> Preparing tests... failed.
>
> Error: Unable to find test runner app within /Users/runner/runners/2.164.8/work/1/a/DerivedData/Build/Products/Staging-iphoneos
> [error]Error: /usr/local/bin/appcenter failed with return code: 3

Answer (score 0):

> How to run XCTest (UI test cases) of iOS mobile application in the azure pipeline?

According to the document [Using Azure DevOps for UI Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin#xcuitest), you need make sure the  Arguments in the Advanced section of the `Xcode` task , specify a derived data path, typically using `-derivedDataPath DerivedData`.

Bsides, You will also need an `.ipa` file for your application. An you can build the `.ipa` file in the same Xcode build-for-testing task by checking the Create app package option, or in a separate Xcode build step or in a Bash script step.

Hope this helps.